Карта видеозахвата для монитора 16:10
Пытаюсь найти карту видеозахвата, которая поддерживает соотношение сторон 16:10, желательно, с разрешение 1920*1200. Такие вообще бывают?
Погуглив нашёл только древние вопросы на реддите:

Is there anyway, with any Elgato Capture Card, to capture a 16:10 aspect ratio. - 2 года назад с ответом нет и ссылкой на пост 8-летней давности.
16:10 display issues - 8 лет назад с ответом, что таких карт не существует.
Capture cards that support 16:10 aspect ratios? - 4 года назад без ответов, но в вопросе предполагается, что Epiphan Av.io4k может выполнять такую запись, но стоит слишком дорого (гугл говорит, что сейчас её цена 650 долларов). В описании на сайте действительно указано 1920*1200. 

Такие устройства за адекватную сумму вообще существуют? Если нет, то почему? Какая устройству захвата разница, соотношение сторон 4:3, 16:9 или 16:10?

не в теме. Но разве нельзя взять устройство захвата с бòльшим разрешениеим и на уровне ПО забирать нужное, насколько я понимаю, не популярное 1920*1200?

@Dmitry, оно масштабирует получаемый сигнал под выходное разрешение для usb. А кастомные разрешения просто не ест - ошибка вместо вывода. При этом (для устройств с выходом) по hdmi оно дальше прокидывает то же, что на входе, но на usb получается отмасштабированная картинка. Можно программно растягивать обратно, но очевидно, что это с ухудшением качества (по крайней мере, если устройство не x10 от оригинального размера выдаёт).

да, здесь надо знать эти тонкости. Как я и говорил я не в теме. успехов в поиске решения. Чисто для инфо, глянул на своих рынках, ничего даже рядом нет. Только упомянутый Epiphan, по цене выше чем 650 долларов.

@Dmitry, на али цены начинаются от $5 за hdmi in, usb out и от $12 за hdmi in, usb+hdmi out. Поэтому я вообще не понимаю, что там такого надо накрутить, чтобы получилось $650...
